# Доктрина не обновляет свойства объекта cmf SeoBundle после установки

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, clone

Я использую Symfony CMF SeoBundle. Мой класс сущности использует SeoAwareTrait. Когда я пытаюсь обновить свои свойства SEO (я использую код ниже), я получаю результат со старыми значениями свойств.

```
$entity = $this->galleryManager->findByLink($link);

            $entity->getSeoMetadata()->setTitle($metaTitle);
            $entity->getSeoMetadata()->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
            $entity->getSeoMetadata()->setMetaKeywords($metaKeywords);

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
```

Когда я пытаюсь клонировать мои seo-свойства, Doctrine успешно сохраняет мои новые значения:

```
$entity = $this->galleryManager->findByLink($link);

            $entity->getSeoMetadata()->setTitle($metaTitle);
            $entity->getSeoMetadata()->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
            $entity->getSeoMetadata()->setMetaKeywords($metaKeywords);

            $entity->setSeoMetadata(clone $entity->getSeoMetadata());

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
```

Почему во втором случае доктрина обновляет результат, а в первом нет? Правильно ли я понимаю, что доктрина не воспринимает изменения свойств, которые относятся к другим объектам?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вы не указали правила каскадирования.
Например, это можно сделать в аннотации к полю модели с помощью параметра cascade={"persist", "remove", ...}, который обеспечивает каскадирование соответствующих операций.

Более подробно можно посмотреть здесь https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations